# Unable to 'call' controller action from ajax post

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using net.core for the first time today and I'm trying to call an action method from an ajax call:

My Ajax call (from a normal HTML page)

```
$("#contactMap").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var url = "/MapObjects/mapContact";
    //I've tried MapObjectsController &         '@Url.Action("mapContact", 'MapObjects")'; But to no avail

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
            alert("success");
        }
    });

});
```

And in my controller:

```
namespace myName.Controllers
{
    

public class MapObjectsController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult mapContact()
    {
        Account account = new Account();

        return Json(account);
    }
}
```

}

The 'account' is just a normal model (obvs empty in this case). All I receive is a 404 error in the console though.

As mentioned this is the 1st time I've .net Core (this is code I've written loads of times in 'normal' MVC projects) so it's possible that I'm missing something really obvious.

Thanks,
C

Comment: Hi @SxChoc, can it work when you send request by postman? Did you use route template like: `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints ={endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default",pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");});`? Please share your Startup.cs.

Answer (score 0):

The first, try to call the `@Url.Action()` explicitly in the Ajax call :

```
$("#contactMap").click(function (e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("mapContact", "MapObjects")',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        cache: false,
        success: function (result) {
                alert("success");
            }
    });
});
```

The second, check your routing rules.